# Oracle Statement not complete

Tags: oracle10g

I got an Oracle database statement which displays the data of the last 7 days in my script

The statement is :

Code:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
WHERE  DATETIME BETWEEN  to_char((sysdate-7,MM), 'DDMMYYYY%') AND
       to_char((sysdate,MM), 'DDMMYYYY%')
ORDER BY DATETIME ASC;
```

But, this output gives me the results of the previous months data aslo on that particular week

Quote:
DATETIME format is DDMMYYYY HH:MI
How to get only this months data and not the previous months data

Comment: a) why isn't `DATETIME` of type DTAE ? b) Why this format ? what does it mean to order by it ? if you use a string as a date (don't, but if you do) better use `yyyymmddhh24mi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make DATETIME a date instead:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
WHERE  to_date(DATETIME, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI') BETWEEN  case when to_char(sysdate, 'dd') > 7 then sysdate-7 else trunc(sysdate,'mm') end AND
       sysdate
ORDER BY DATETIME ASC;
```

Comment: The above statement is giving me following error when executed
"ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12"

Comment: This is giving me the whole months data starting from 1st not the previous week data
The sysdate format is mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS

Comment: Current sysdate 3/26/2012 1:39:03 PM
and datetime for last record is 14012012 20:51

Comment: @user1292831- sorry for my typos ... changed the 'mm' to 'dd'

Comment: There is again a problem, this gives the data for the the last 7 days taking the current time. so I am getting the data of the 1st day starting from afternoon but not from the start of the day (00:00). 

Is there anyway to fix this?